# Make ASP.NET-Core WebApi Server compatible with legacy WCF Client xml httppost requests (xml serializer xmlns namespace 500 internal server error)

Tags: xml, wcf, asp.net-core-webapi, datacontractserializer, asp.net-core-6.0

we are moving our CodeBase from .NET 4.8 WCF to .NET 6 WebApi but still have some legacy WCF clients.
These clients connect with legacy WCF (SOAP HTTP-POST XML) with small deserialized DataContracts to the server. No black magic.
As far as i know, **WCF is using the DataContractSerializer** to serialize to XML, right?

When a legacy client connects to the WebApi Server i get 500 internal server error due to the namespaces (xmlns: .... datacontract.org...) in the WCF-generated xml. (The generated XMLSerializer code reads the namespace and throws an error beacuse its not defined)

```
<DataContract xmlns:i="http://... datacontract.org/....namespace">
</DataContract>
```

(How) is it possible to make ASP.NET-Core WebApi compatible with WCF clients (http post xml) and accept/ignore these namespaces in requests and generate them for responses to satisfy the WCF client?

Maybe something with Input/OutputFormatter ?

Thank you very much and have a nice-sunny-not-so-hot-day ;)

Comment: Did you see this?  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrading-a-wcf-service-to-dotnet-6/  Does that help at all?

Comment: Also, is your problem with model binding, formatting of returned results, or both?

Comment: i dont think CoreWCF can run side-by-side (same port) with webapi?
I think the problem is both. I get valid XML with some xmlns namespaces which get rejected and returned results which dont contain the namespaces and get rejected by the legacy client.